# How to create in Jquery page slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hello I'm very new in Jquery I would say just know how to write very basic code in JQuery.

I have an idea to make `page slider`, when I click on url to go to different page instend of roughly process of downloading the page,

```
like: blank screen --> picture rendering --> file loading and so on,
```

it just slide to the left.

Is this possible with my level in `Jquery`? And how can I do this?

Thank you folks.

Answer (score 0):

With the level of jQuery you know. you should go with [**jQuery Cycle Plugin**](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

Comment: Thank you sir for any help. Why the link does not open?